# NodeJS/Lambda/Lex/Axios - How to make a synchronous call for slot(s)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, axios, synchronous, aws-lex

I've done my research in regards with making a `synchronous` calls and it is not recommended as it is blocking the thread. But in my case, it's different.

I am making a simple weather checker `amazon lex` bot. And I have two slots, `{city}` and `{date}`. When the client ask the bot `"Check the weather"`, the bot will then ask the client which city they wanted to check. When the user sends back the `{city}`, there is where my `axios` from `lambda` sends a get request to `openWeatherMap` api.

The problem is, after the clients gave the `{city}` where he/she wanna check the weather in, the next slot which is the `{date}` immediately fire without waiting for the axios call to get finished.

And why am I wanted to wait? Because the `axios` call may return an error and I want to capture it and display immediately to the client so that the process will be ended.

**Important**: Do not get confuse with `{date}` slot, I don't really wanted to get the date. I just make it as example, but the concern is to wait for the axios response from the first slot before the following slot will get triggered.

Comment: Are you saying that your Lambda is responding with a request for the date before completing the call to openWeatherMap api? Or are you saying your Lambda is receiving two slots from the client {city} {date}, and you want to complete check weather based on {city} before weather check based on {city} and {date}? Either way, it'll probably be best if you post the relevant code in your question.

Comment: HI @KMo, sorry for the confusion. The first one you mention is what actually happening. When the clients send the city, my axios from lambda sends a get request to weather api, but before the request ends and before i get the response, the next slot which is the date is immediately fire.